# why does this query return an empty set in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm using jdbc to connect with MySQL server. My current subjects table in the database with its entries are.

```
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+-------+----------+
| sub_no | name      | lec_no | credits | price | semester |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+-------+----------+
|  cs001 | network 1 | lec001 |       3 |  3000 |        7 |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------+-------+----------+
```

but when I run `SELECT credits,price,semester from subjects WHERE sub_no ="cs001"` why does MySQL return an empty set instead of `3, 3000, 7`

Comment: Can you show your table definition in your question?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE subjects`

You might also have to be more careful with spaces, put a space after each comma in your query, and after the = sign.

Comment: the code for the create table subjects is  CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
  `sub_no` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `lec_no` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `credits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  semester int
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: @marper96 You have a space before "cs001" in your database.

Comment: yup sorry guys for wasting your time I didn't notice that.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's because mysql is searching for "cs001" and not cs001. Try removing the quotes and see what happens.